# How get image from images model to home page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am developing an ecommerce website with Django. In my home page displayed product cards as you see in the below image.

[image]

This product image in each card I take from my Product model (image field). When I hover over this image on the home page, the image is changing to another image. That is for I need another image, and I want to take the next image (display when I hover over) from my Product_images model. But I don't know how to do that.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = 
    path('', views.home_page, name='amd-home'),
    path('product/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='amd-about'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product, Product_image, Product_details

def home_page(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    images = Product_image.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'images':images}
    return render(request, 'product/home.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price_old = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    internal_storage = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}, {self.description}'

class Product_image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.title} image'
```

**home.html**
my template file is a very large file, so I only insert the element where I get an image from the Product model (this code word fine), but I don't know how to write code to take images from my Product_image model.

```
{% for product in products %}
 <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.id %}"><img alt="" src="{{ product.image.url }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your model you can give a related_name field like :

```
class Product_image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_images)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.title} image'
```

Then you can access the product's images in template like:

```
{% for product in products %}
     <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.id %}"> </a>
 {% for image in product.product_images.all %}
    <img alt="" src="{{ image.image.url }}">
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

PS: You dont have to return all Product_image quesryset from the view

Expanding on the answer, if you want to order the images there are different approaches you can take:

Method1:

```
class Product_image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_images)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.title} image'
   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time_created']
```

This will order the query set from first created to last . If you don't want to add a time created field you can also choose to order by id.

Method2:

Add a property to your Product model:

```
    class Product:
           ....
    @property
    def sorted_image_set(self):
        return self.product_images.order_by('time_created')
```

Then you can access this property from the template

```
  {% for image in product.sorted_image_set %}
```

Method 3 :

Creating a custom template tag to support order_by in template

```
@register.filter
def order_by(queryset, args):
    args = [x.strip() for x in args.split(',')]
    return queryset.order_by(*args)
```

Then you can do :

```
{% for image in product.product_images|order_by:"time_created" %}
```

After the list has been ordered you can access it just by the array indexes like for example images[0] or images[1]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already solved problem with you answer.
I want additionally ask you. with this code {{ image.image.url }} in my template I get last added image to my Product_image model, but how I can get second image or first image in Product_image model. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change src in your HTML

```
{% for product in products %}
   <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.id %}"><img alt="" src="/media/uploads/{{ 
   product.image }}"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

I have assumed that you have `MEDIA_URL=/media/` in your settings. Change this in src if you have different `MEDIA_URL`

Comment: that html code work fine which I wrote, how you can see in image in my question from Product model I already take image without any problem. But I don't know how get image from my Product_image model to my home.html file.